# Get data angularjs sends back directly into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form that creates a new object with angularjs. The data is sent back under the name marker.

```
$scope.createMarker = function() {

    $http.post('/markers/create', $scope.marker)
        .success(function(data) {

        })
        .error(function(data) {
              console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };
```

So in my markers.ejs, I get the value back :

```
 <input id="marker"> {{marker}} </input>
```

But I would like to get it directly in a javascript function :

```
 console.log({{marker}})
```

Is it possible ?

For now I have the solution of stocking it into the input and get it with jquery:

```
     <input id="marker" value="{{marker}}"> </input>

     <script> console.log($("#marker").val()) </script>
```

But could we directly pass it into the js ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS encourages separation of presentation and controllers. If you intend to use a JS function directly, there is to need to do anything in your `.ejs` file, which is meant for presentation only.

Therefore, you should call `console.log(marker)` (or `console.log($scope.marker)`) directly in your success callback.

Comment: Thanks ! In this case I will keep it separated. It is good to know that there is a solution, in case.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. Put in the success case something like this

```
success(data){
    var Mydata=data
}
```

and out from it

```
$scope.marker=Mydata
```

so you can bind the variable to you html element